# How to create standalone Rmath.h library to access R functions in C?

Tags: r, c, windows

I am facing difficulties in creating `Rmath.dll`. I have already referred to several sources:

1. [R-exts 6.17: Using these functions in your own C code](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Standalone-Mathlib)
2. [R-admin 9: The standalone Rmath library](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-admin.html#The-standalone-Rmath-library)
3. [Using the R Standalone Math Library](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/%7Espector/s243/rmath.html)

The problems which I am facing are as follows:

1. My R (4.1.0) installation directory does not contain the `src/nmath/standalone` directory to build the library as mentioned in "6.17 Using these functions in your own C code".
2. I tried building the library by downloading and extracting the `R-4.1.0.tar` file and then following the instructions given here in [R-admin](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/R-admin.html#Windows-standalone). But still getting the error **"undefined reference to `dnorm4'"** after executing the command as shown below:

   ```
   gcc -g -c -o Interoperate.o Interoperate.c -ID:/R-4.1.0/src/include -LD:/R-4.1.0/src/nmath/standalone/  -lRmath -lm
   ```

`Interoperate.c` contains the following code:

```
#define MATHLIB_STANDALONE
#include <R.h>
#include <Rmath.h>

int main()
{
/*  Inputs  */
    double V1 = 1;
    double V2 = 2;

/*  Normal Distribution  */ 
    double result = dnorm(V1, V2, M_PI, 1);
    printf("%lf\n",result);
    return 0;
}
```

I am out of options now. I need help with this issue.

Comment: That is _not_ an Rcpp question so I will remove the `[rcpp]` tag. The library can optionally be built when you build R.

Answer (score 1):

You generally build `libRmath.a` -- the Rmath library -- when building R. It is done each and every time the Debian (and Ubuntu) packages are built because I have set it up that way.  Now it may been decades since I last tried this on Windows so I cannot help you with that part -- but at the end of the day it is a call to `ar` that glues the files together so if you know how to do this you may be able to do it by hand.

Your example works fine here (on Ubuntu):

```
$ gcc -o answer answer.c -lRmath -I /usr/share/R/include
$ ./answer 
-2.114329
$ 
$ ldd answer
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffe3a391000)
        libRmath.so.1 => /usr/lib/libRmath.so.1 (0x00007f12e10b8000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f12e0ece000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f12e0d7f000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f12e0d5d000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f12e111f000)
$
```